# NSURLProtocol & swift - error in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, nsurlprotocol

I tried to implement a NSURLProtocol as explained in the following tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift

Everything works fine with iOS8 but in iOS7 I get a runtime error in startLoading().

```
override func startLoading() {
    var newRequest = self.request.copy() as NSMutableURLRequest //<- this line fails
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "MyURLProtocolHandledKey", inRequest: newRequest)

    self.connection = NSURLConnection(request: newRequest, delegate: self)
}
```

Error: WebCore: CFNetwork Loader(10): EXC_BREAKPOINT

Does anyone have successfully implemented a NSURLProtocol? Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you use `var newRequest = self.request.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest`? Because I wouldn't expect copy() to return a mutable request.

Comment: Cool; I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that a copy of a (non-mutable) NSURLRequest is another, non-mutable NSURLRequest, which therefore can't be cast to an NSMutableURLRequest. Try:

```
var newRequest = self.request.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest // mutableCopy() instead of copy()
```

This should give you a mutable copy of the original request, which should cast just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in latest version of XCode (6.0.1), it is not possible to cast `NSURLRequest` to `NSMutableURLRequest`

Here is the swift compiler error message:

```
'NSURLRequest' is not convertible to 'NSMutableURLRequest'
```

You can create an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest` in this alternative way

```
var newRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self.request.URL, 
               cachePolicy: self.request.cachePolicy, 
               timeoutInterval: self.request.timeoutInterval)
```

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! Just in order to improve myself, how did you see the swift compiler error message? The only hint I see is the CFNetwork Loader error.

Comment: I just have a hunch that it is type conversion issue. I wrote a simple type cast in playground and swift emitted the said error message. So you won't see this particular error message in your project

Comment: Anthony, I had troubles with your solution on some pages which require a login. Creating a mutable copy as Matt suggested works.